# How to change text input value in Bootstrap modal?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

I have this text input in my Laravel PHP blade template:

```
<input type="text" name="friendly_name" value="{{ $trunk->friendly_name }}">
```

When I view this in the web browser, I see the text input populated with the value of `$trunk->friendly_name`, and I can use the browser console to check the value with jQuery:

```
console.log($('[name=friendly_name]').val())
```

And see the value of `$trunk->friendly_name`. All is well - so far.

**Here's my problem:**
In the web browser, I click into the text input and change the text in the text input. But when I do `console.log` again, I still get the old value and not the new value I just typed.

Why? And how do I get the new value with jQuery?

In an attempt to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I created a simple HTML file containing just the text input (and with jQuery loaded), and `console.log` returns the new typed value as I expect. <del>So I was thinking it must be the fact that I'm initially setting the input value with a PHP variable, but can't figure out why.</del>

Thanks for help!

**UPDATE**
As I was admiring my question, I realized I left something out: the text input is in a Bootstrap modal. So I moved the input out of the modal, and now it works as expected. So now I have something new to Google. I'll leave this question up in case anyone already knows the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Found the answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38982152/3882035. You have to add the modal id to your jQuery selector.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure jQuery is loaded.

Second, in order to detect that the value has been changed you need an event listener.  So we are going to use the jQuery `change()` to handle this.  We will wrap the listener inside of the `document.ready()` function.

Third, I added an id to the input tag so we can use the id to reference the input.

See if any of this helps you.

```
<input type="text" id ="friendly_name" name="friendly_name" value="{{ $trunk->friendly_name }}">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>      

  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#friendly_name').change(function() {
      Console.log("This is your text input value: " + $('#friendly_name').val());
    });

  });

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at this! Not sure if adding an id to the input helps or not. But including the modal's id in my jQuery selector did! Weird. Have a good one!

Comment: Hey glad it worked for you.  Your question was fairly well written but you did not add enough code in your question.  Had you had more code for us to see, I might have been able to tell you were using a modal and found the problem that way.  It just saves everyone time and energy and lets us get straight to the point.  Anyways, just a friendly suggestion.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.on` [event](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('input[name="friendly_name"]').on('change click keyup', function() {
      console.log("This is your text input value: " + $(this).val());
    });

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="friendly_name" value="{{ $trunk->friendly_name }}">
```